# How to check how namy connections has mongodb server and waht limit present in conf and waht default?

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb 4.4.0 and symfony project with queue and a lot of consumers, I faced with some problem, when many consumer executing jobs, saving a lot of products in db, server CPU loading fast inrease. I want to check how many connection I have at some moment, investigated doc I found info aobut limitation connections and this is equal 64k, this mean 64 000, correct ? But I want to understand how many connections opened at some moment for that I executed this command in shell

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

But faced with empty result, original result lokks like this - `script executed successfull but there are no result`. Why? And how to check ? I tested it on machine where present mongo - 4.15.0-117-generic.

in machine where I executed docker-compose up for mongobd imgs

```
$ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       193076
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  16384
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 193076
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

and exactlry in mongodb container

```
root@mongodb:/# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 193076
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

but strange case when my consumers worked and query `db.serverStatus().connections` retun empty result.
Actually I faced with slowly speed when my consumers instert many rows in documents, first what I did, this is use transaction and this is help, but after some time I faced with slow speed again, right now I thinking about sharding my mongodb, could it approach to resolve problem with speed when many consumers execute instert a lot of rows in documents ?

**UPDATE**

I ececuted this command in shell directly and faced with the same empty result

```
> db.serverStatus().connections
> db
test
> db
test
> use symfony
switched to db symfony
> db.serverStatus().connections
> db.serverStatus().connections
>
```

Comment: 64k means 65536. It's default value and can be changed in the config or command line. It has no effect if it is higher than system limits like ulimit on linux. Each connection uses something like 1Mb of RAM. Ensure you have enough. Pagefaults can easily melt a CPU with disk IOs. Empty connections make no sense. Neither does the last sentence. What was you trying to say in russian/ukrainian? Does db.serverStatus() return anything? It requires at least ClusterMonitor permissions.

Comment: If your deployment requires auth, ensure you are authenticted.

Comment: @Alex Blex when I executed command `db.serverStatus().connections` in shell, I had result - `script executed successfull but there are no result`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Is it shell or robomongo?

Comment: yep, I opened shell in robomongo (Robo 3T 1.3.1) and executed query inside.

Comment: @AlexBlex I uddated my question

Comment: yeah, they re-branded robomongo to 3T after acquisition, and it 's not the shell by any means. "Shell" in context of mongodb refers to the particular opensource command line client maintained by mongodb. It has some very specific features documented at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/ All other clients are documented elsewhere and some of them like Robo 3T are proprietary and quite opaque.

Comment: Anyway, the connection thingy. Me myself and D already asked if the user has enough privileges but didn't get any answer so I'll repeat the question - what roles are assigned to the user you are using to connect to mongodb and does `db.serverStatus()` return anything at all?